# How to prove $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B) \implies f(A) \subseteq B $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Take $x\in f(A) $
$\iff f^{-1}(x)\in A$
$\implies f^{-1}(x) \in f^{-1}(B)$
$\implies x\in f(f^{-1}(B) \subseteq B $
$\implies x \in B $

Are all steps ok or not?
I specially doubt with the $1$st step. Is that both side directions true for that step?

Comment: Do you know if $f$ is bijective? Otherwise you can't write $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: You should say that $\exists y\in A: f(y) =x$. And then you can proceed as normal.

Comment: From $x\in f(A)$ you can write $\{x\} \subset f(A)$ and $f^{-1} \{x\} \subset A$ using only preimage definition, which always exists, without giving meaning to $f^{-1}$ separately, which can make sense only for injective case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y\in f(A)$, then there is an $x\in A$ such that $y=f(x)$. Now hypothesis gives $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ which gives $f(x)(=y)\in B$. Hence, $f(A)\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in A$. Since $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)=\{y\in dom f \,:\, f(y)\in B\}$, then $f(x)\in B$. Thus $f(A)\subseteq B$.

Conversely, let's suppose $f(A)\subseteq B$. Pick $x\in A$. Then $f(x)\in B$ and so $x \in \{y\in dom f \,:\, f(y)\in B\}=f^{-1}(B)$.